# How to calculate rotated global location coordinates (Long, Lat)?

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-geometry

Given the current global location coordinate system:
 -180 <-> 180 Longitude
 -90  <-> 90  Latitude
A rotation of the globe 90 degrees counter-clockwise around the Y-axis would bring the north pole to the west and the south pole to the east.
North Pole would become from (0, 90) the new location (-90, 0);
A point at (0,45) would become (-45,0).
I need a way to compute this new rotated point for any given point on the sphere(earth.)
Thank you for any assistance.